# Data racing on python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm making n-body simulator with Python, and trying to apply multiple CPU and CUDA with PyCUDA.

I made a Single-Process version. this is the code:

```
from pyglet.gl import *
from math import pi, sin, cos
from vector import Vector
from body import Body

body_list = []

def calcula_cpu(dt):
    n = len(body_list)
    f = [Vector([0, 0]) for _ in range(n)]
    for i in range(n): # Huge calculation on this part. O(n^2)
        for j in range(n):
            if i != j:
                body_i = body_list[i]
                body_j = body_list[j]
                f[i] += body_i.forceFrom(body_j)
    for i in range(n): # Actual part of this function. applying force on bodies.
        body_list[i].move(f[i], dt)

def draw_circle(body, width, height):
    size = body.getsize()
    x, y = body.getPos()
    x += width // 2
    y += height // 2
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    for i in range(12):
        theta = 2 * pi * i / 12
        glVertex2f(size * cos(theta) + x, size * sin(theta) + y)
    glEnd()

class MainWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        self._trace = False
        config = Config(sample_buffers=1, samples=16,
                        depth_size=16, double_buffer=True, )
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(resizable=True, config=config,
                                         caption='N-Body Simulation',
                                         vsync=True)
        self._trail = False
        self._margin = 30

    def on_draw(self):
        # OpenGL initialization.
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        glLoadIdentity()
        # Draw Axises.
        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        glVertex2f(self.width // 2, self._margin)
        glVertex2f(self.width // 2, self.height - self._margin)
        glVertex2f(self._margin, self.height // 2)
        glVertex2f(self.width - self._margin, self.height // 2)
        glEnd()
        # Draw Bodies
        for body in body_list:
            draw_circle(body, self.width, self.height)

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, _):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 5
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            body_list.append(Body(Vector([-5*(n-1)+i*10, -5*(n-1)+j*10]), Vector([0,0]), 5))
    window = MainWindow()

    pyglet.clock.set_fps_limit(60)
    pyglet.clock.schedule(calcula_cpu)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

I refered Body and Vector classes, do some customization(removing draw function, etc), in these website: [body.py and vector.py](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/34nbody/)

And, it works almost perfectly.

Based on the Single-Process version, I wrote a Multi-Process version of it:

```
from pyglet.gl import *
from math import pi, sin, cos
import multiprocessing as mp
from vector import Vector
from body import Body


body_list = []
p = object

def calcula_safe(body_tuple):
    target_body, other_body_list, dt = body_tuple
    f = Vector([0,0])
    for b in other_body_list:
        f += target_body.forceFrom(b)
    target_body.move(f, dt)
    return target_body

def calcula_mp(dt):
    n = len(body_list)
    argum = []
    for i in body_list:
        argum.append((i, [x for x in body_list if x is not i], dt, ))
    result = p.map_async(calcula_safe, argum).get()
    body_list.clear()
    for i in result:
        body_list.append(i)


def draw_circle(body, width, height):
    ...draw circle...

class MainWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    ...drawing work...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    th = 4  # Process number.
    p = mp.Pool(processes=4)

    n = 5
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            body_list.append(Body(Vector([-5*(n-1)+i*10, -5*(n-1)+j*10]), Vector([0,0]), 5))
    window = MainWindow()

    pyglet.clock.set_fps_limit(60)
    pyglet.clock.schedule(calcula_mp)
    pyglet.app.run()
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

But this works differently comparing with Single-Process version:

- The Single-Process version, it shows point symmetry in medium of n-bodies.
- But in Multi-Process version, symmetry is broken. (I can't upload images).
- Same phenomenon on Multi-Process version with 1-thread: I think this is a hint.

What's happening with my code?

Comment: Well, you are never actually using the pool so no wonder it does not work. But what are you trying to achieve here? What exactly is the part of the process you want to run with multiprocessing? Let me warn you: you do *NOT* want to try multiprocess-rendering.

Comment: Besides, you are talking about CUDA, but I do not see anything CUDA related in your code. Well, I'm certainly no expert in it, but as I see it, you are just using pyglet and opengl.

Comment: @TeemuRisikko yes, I don't want to make **multiprocess-rendering system**, even I didn't think it is possible. I used multiprocessing for calculating newton gravity, having O(n^2) time complexity. _NO THEORETICAL OPTIMIZATION_(such as Barnes–Hut simulation), I could understand its principles but maybe next(PyCUDA), next time. Just for easing O(n^2) calculation.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I thought that @KeanuJeon wanted a CUDA version of the multi-process version. If you aren't interested in PyCUDA I would recommend to remove it from the question, as now the introduction could be misleading.

Comment: And yes, there is no CUDA code, because I made single-process version first, multi-process is next and PyCUDA is third...and even I didn't study C/C++ CUDA yet. @Marcs edited my question some awful grammer, with adding tag of CUDA, even though I didn't touch any parts of CUDA on this question.
Anyway, I'm using pyglet as GUI library for express n-body simulation **in 2D Plane**, and I want to know what exactly happened on these code, and find mistakes or misundertanding of multiprocessing in python.

Comment: @Marcs that's my fault, I shouldn't mentioned PyCUDA on this question making confusion. PyCUDA is just for next step after the multiprocessing.